# Print all of a scrollable textbox

Tags: vb.net, printing, streamreader

Programming in VB.NET and have another slight issue. I have a `TextBox` that is populated from a txt file using a `StreamReader`. Basically I have a print option but can only print what is shown in the `TextBox`, if there is more info in the `TextBox` further down that needs to be scrolled this is not printed (hope that makes sense!). Is there any way I get get around this so all of the information is printed?

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class JobList
    Private Sub JobList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\test\JobLog.txt", True)
        txtJL.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub printText(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim font As New Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular)
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(txtJL.Text, font, Brushes.Black, 100, 100)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        Dim printDoc As New PrintDocument
        AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.printText
        printDoc.Print()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to print from a `StreamReader` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx), scroll down - there is an example. It may need a slight modification to print from a `String`, then you can pass `TextBox.Text` into it. Or just use AS IS and print from `StreamReader` - should get same results anyway.